# Actionbar navigation list not cancellable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

There is something weird about actionbar's navigation list.
I use Sherlock's actionbar, but the problem is also in the native ics actionbar.

When using the app, and clicking on the actionbar's navigation list, the list cannot be closed without selecting an item from the list, or clicking the actionbar navigation button (the same place where you open it). Touching the background or pressing the back button doesn't close the list.
Tried it on Gmail app, it closes on touch and on back button.

Btw: I have a custom spinner adapter for the navigation list.

Thnx :-)

Comment: err... It *does* close, when you press outside the spinner.

Comment: Agreed. Here is a sample project that works just fine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ListNav

Comment: Ok, I don't know what I just did, but somehow it works now... I know it should, but it didn't at first, maybe I did something wrong, never mind now it's perfect, it was really pissing me off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, it works now :D, just check your implementation maybe I did something wrong from before.